# network request failed, react native, ios , ios app expo

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I use react native to sent a GET request ,but react native return network 
request failed. 
I do not know to fix it.
I use fetch send a request, I can get resource in my browser https://localhost:3011/hello and https://my ip number:3011/hello .

but I can not get request ok in my fetch .
my code is

---

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: '666',
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://localhost:3011/hello')
      .then(response => (response)=> response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({content: '789'});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({content: '123'});
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.item}>{this.state.content}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.item}>999</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I final get this.state.content is '123'. so there is a error .
And I search a lot pages for information can not help.
And I change `localhost` to  `my ip` or `10.0.2.2` or `10.0.3.2` also can not help .
I run my app in expo.

Comment: I've face the same issue, did you solve it?
I changed the IP address to my local address is not working too

Comment: Any news? I have the same problem.